# ImageLayout.Center does not center background image

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to center a background image. However the background image is larger than my control(which is a flat style checkbox).

[A picture to make my problem clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eymYR.png)
[image]

Usually if the background image is smaller than the control, it will be shown like the black box(which is properly centered); but in my case it will show partial image in the green box(left top corner), but the end result I want is the orange box(the center of the image), or zoomed proportionally to fill the control with extra part cut off(ImageLayout.Zoom will show whole image with blank space).

Update: Code used:

```
        Image img = Image.FromFile("xxxx.png");
        mycheckbox.BackgroundImage = img;
        mycheckbox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
```

Comment: Have you tried with ImageLayout.Strech? You could also provide some code, it helps :)

Comment: @msmolcic Stretch will give a distorted image. Code is really trivial but I will put it in. For this particular case I could get away with using checkBox.Image property instead of .BackgroundImage but it will only work if the image is larger than the control, and not every control has .Image property so I want to see a more generic solution.

Comment: Generally: when you have a list of possible values I suggest trying them all out. One of them should work properly.

Comment: @Mitulátbáti I did and none worked. I guess I might need to go down the Graphics path instead of using Control properties :/

Comment: To get the orange box, you can set the `Image` property instead of the `BackGroundImage`  (with `ImageAlign = MiddleCenter`), but I don't know if that's suitable for all your images?

Comment: @Me.Name I have tried this, it almost worked; however if the image is taller but narrower than the control, it still leaves blank on left and right sides.

Comment: If it's acceptable to resize the image before hand, it could be checked if it's smaller than the checkbox bounds and if so, multiply with the largest ratio. This would solve the filling, but would not be dynamic in case the checkbox size changes during runtime. Doesn't fit rightly in the comments, so will post an answer with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image` can be used instead of `BackgroundImage` to get the part of the image as the orange rectangle of the example.

If the image doesn't fill the entire checkbox and if it's acceptable to alter the image being set (should work without problems, but would not be dynamic in case the checkbox size changes during runtime), the image could be resized first according to the largest ratio:

```
        var img = Image.FromFile("xxxx.png");
        float ratio = Math.Max(mycheckbox.Height / (float)img.Height,mycheckbox.Width / (float)img.Width);            
        if (ratio > 1)
        {
            Func<float, int> calc = f => (int)Math.Ceiling(f * ratio);
            var bmp = new Bitmap(img,  calc(img.Width ), calc(img.Height ));
            img.Dispose();
            img = bmp;
        }
        mycheckbox.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        mycheckbox.Image = img;
```

The line `float ratio = Math.Max(mycheckbox.Height / (float)img.Height,mycheckbox.Width / (float)img.Width);` simply calculates both the height ratio and the width ratio. If either is larger than 1, it means the checkbox height or width is larger. It doesn't matter which one, only which is larger, hence the Math.Max. The check of larger than 1 is performed on the largest ratio and if needed the image is enlarged with said ratio.

***Edit*** A more generic approach, that scales and cuts the image so that if fills the control size and the `BackGroundImage` property can be used:

```
    public static void SetImage(this Control ctrl, Image img)
    {
        var cs = ctrl.Size;
        if (img.Size != cs)
        {
            float ratio = Math.Max(cs.Height / (float)img.Height, cs.Width / (float)img.Width);
            if (ratio > 1)
            {
                Func<float, int> calc = f => (int)Math.Ceiling(f * ratio);
                img = new Bitmap(img, calc(img.Width), calc(img.Height));                    
            }

            var part = new Bitmap(cs.Width, cs.Height);
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(part))
            {
                g.DrawImageUnscaled(img, (cs.Width - img.Width) /2, (cs.Height - img.Height) / 2);
            }                
            img = part;
        }
        ctrl.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
        ctrl.BackgroundImage = img;
    }
```

Comment: Again, not every Control has `Image` property, e.g. `Panel`. Or if you need `Image` property for other use, you should go with `Graphics.DrawImage()`. However after trying out, I found that `Panel` is very sluggish with draw calls, but `Button` and `CheckBox` are not(using exactly the same calls). Whichever way, the image need to be scaled if necessary, thanks for the image scaling code!

Comment: oops, completely missed the comment where you mentioned Image and BackgroundImage yourself and mentioned the other control types. Only saw the answer you made to my own comment, so didn't realise it had to work for other controls too, sorry about that. But indeed, even if custom painting is used, the same scaling can be used.

Comment: @anetworknoobie , rebasing the requirements of multiple control types, the image could be altered thus, that only the required part remains and backgroundImage can be used to ensure general use. If you want, I could try to add that to the answer.